# LINQ on a double**

Tags: c#, linq

I have an unmanaged 2d array (`double A**`) representing a matrix. Each of the **n** rows is a **m**-dimensional vector. And I have the function `GetRelation(double* vector1, double* vector2)` which returns the relation coefficient between two vectors.
So what I was asking about was how can I use LINQ to get the row indexes of the vectors having the largest relations with `A[0]` (the first vector).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Em, I was tring to do it with for loop and a List, but I found it would be easier if I could somehow enumerate my matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var topIndexes = Enumerable.Range(1, n-1)
   .Select(index => new { index, relation = GetRelation(A[0], A[index]) })
   .OrderByDescending (x => x.relation)
   .Select(x => x.index);
```

Comment: Enumerable.Range(1, n-1) this is what I did not know how to do. Worked like a charm, thanks!